# nsetools: list index out of range

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, stock, index-error

I am trying to get the upcoming corporate actions data of all the stocks listed on NSE using [nsetools](https://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I am running into the error list index out of range after getting results for about 355 stocks. The list contains about 1800 stocks.
Here's my code-

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()
all_stock_codes = nse.get_stock_codes()
del all_stock_codes["SYMBOL"]
just_stock_codes = list(all_stock_codes.keys())
print(just_stock_codes)
for code in just_stock_codes:
  print(nse.get_quote(code)["purpose"], nse.get_quote(code)["exDate"], nse.get_quote(code)["recordDate"])
```

I am using colab to run the code. Here's a screenshot of the error -

[image]

Comment: No images of errors, please. Post everything in text format. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888).

Comment: Solved using error handling. Turns out, there was a problem with the some codes from the data.